# How does jQuery solve <script defer> issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I have three js files. All three files are attached to html page without defer: 
1)jquery 
2)file with the following content

```
ugu={
temp:function(s){
  alert(s);
 }
};
```

3)file with the following content

```
$.ajax(....) //line1
ugu.temp("hello");//line2
```

So we see, that third file uses objects from 1 and 2. It doesn't have problems with line1. However line2 has errors if I attach 3 js script to html page without "defer", otherwise it throws error that the browser can't find variable ugu.

The question - how can I make work file 3 without "defer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to declare ugu in the global namespace you should use var.

```
var ugu={
temp:function(s){
  alert(s);
 }
};
```

File 2 will have to be loaded before file 3 will run. You might consider looking into require.js it is handy for this.

Answer (score 1):

What is the order of including your files? In HTML file you should first include jQuery, then file with *ugu* definition, and the third one at last.